# how to get value from raw or xml HTML response by groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to get userToken from this kind of raw response:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 
Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2020 14:48:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Security-Policy: default
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Encoding: gzip

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="https.."/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Portal</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="application/javascript">
      window.__webpack_public_path__ = "https";
      window.pageData = {
          configuration: {
              lang: "en",
              country: "UK",
              customization: (input)
          },
          userToken: "3ae85a89-1905-4120-9a8c-7a5d623b51d6",
          cOMPANY: 'OPEL',
          policies: JSON.parse(INPUT)
```

Unfortunately, i can't get into direct value of userToken, i was trying with this kind of assertion

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)

/*for ( userToken in holder.getNodeValues( "//window.pageData/configuration/userToken" ))
log.info "UserToken : [$userToken]"
*/
def userT = holder["//*:script/@userToken"]
token = (Arrays.toString(userT))
log.info token
```

but still nothing and i'm reciving empty brackets [] ; without @userToken i'm reciving whole part from script tag. Any idea how to deal wit it ?
Will be thankful

In xml response looks like that:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 26 wrz 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>
      <link href="https:" rel="icon"/>
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/>
      <title>Portal Seite</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="root"/>
      <script type="application/javascript">window.__webpack_public_path__ = "https:";
      window.pageData = {
          configuration: {
              lang: "de",
              country: "CH",
              customization: JSON.parse(input)
          },
          userToken: "3ae85a89-1905-4120-9a8c-7a5d623b51d6",
          company: 'OPEL',
          policies: JSON.parse(
      ]]><br/><![CDATA[
     "}]"), 
      ]]><script src="https:" type="text/javascript"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your response is XML. The XML node "script" contains _some_ key-value pairs. The key "window.pageData" contains JSON. The JSON node "userToken" is what you are apparently after. There is no chance that "holder["//*:script/@userToken"]" is going to work. You will have to parse all that in **three** steps.

Comment: Just use Regex and you're done: `userToken: "([a-z0-9-]+)"`, otherwise you would need to load the reponse into a browser and get the userToken object, there is no way to parse HTML as XML and access a JSON in it.

Comment: @MushyPeas, thanks for hint, but in which place of my script I need to put it ? or should I have to change script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate more your question regarding a RegEx solution, you could change your script to:

```
def xml = messageExchange.responseContentAsXml
def pattern = /userToken: "([a-z0-9-]+)"/
def match = xml =~ pattern
def token = (match.find()) ? match.group(1) : null
println token
```